# How can I filter nodes by term (entity reference) with jsonapi?

Tags: 8

My nodes contain an entity reference field, **Ref Term**.  I want to fetch a list of nodes that have a specific term with jsonapi.

In jsonapi, when I fetch nodes, the field with the taxonomy term reference is returned like this:

```
"field_ref_term": {
"type": "taxonomy_term--my_vocabulary",
"id": "b1a97358-9834-499d-aee0-ebb0302fb2c3"
},
```

So, first, I tried this:

```
/jsonapi/node/my_content_type?filter[field_ref_term]=f9c171db-1a1d-4d9a-bb55-5b0f8b033749
```

However, that gave me an error:

```
"title": "Bad Request",
"status": "400",
"detail": "Invalid nested filtering. The field `field_ref_term`, given in the path `field_ref_term` is incomplete, it must end with one of the following specifiers: `id`.",
```

So I tried adding `[id]`:

```
/jsonapi/node/my_content_type?filter[field_ref_term][id]=f9c171db-1a1d-4d9a-bb55-5b0f8b033749
```

That gave me a different error:

```
"detail": "You must provide a valid filter condition. Check that you have set the required keys for your filter.",
```

So I tried a longer version:

```
/jsonapi/node/my_content_type?&filter[term-filter][condition][path]=field_ref_term&filter[term-filter][condition][id]=f9c171db-1a1d-4d9a-bb55-5b0f8b033749
```

That gave me the first error again.  I read [the documentation on filtering](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/filtering).

How can I filter my nodes based on which are tagged with a specific taxonomy term?  (In my case, each node has one and only one taxonomy term in its entity reference field.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, but your syntax was off. This is documented further down in your linked page, in the [Filter Examples > Get nodes by a value of a entity reference section](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/filtering#s-2-get-nodes-by-a-value-of-a-entity-reference).

```
SHORT
filter[uid.id][value]=BB09E2CD-9487-44BC-B219-3DC03D6820CD

NORMAL
filter[author-filter][condition][path]=uid.id
filter[author-filter][condition][value]=BB09E2CD-9487-44BC-B219-3DC03D6820CD
```

So, in your example, you'd need to use:

```
SHORT
/jsonapi/node/my_content_type?filter[field_ref_term.id][value]=f9c171db-1a1d-4d9a-bb55-5b0f8b033749

LONG
/jsonapi/node/my_content_type?filter[term-filter][condition][path]=field_ref_term.id&filter[term-filter][condition][value]=f9c171db-1a1d-4d9a-bb55-5b0f8b033749
```